# wordpress creates incorrect .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am wondering why I am having this issue. My site displays "Internal Server Error" ocasinally. When I check the htaccess

I got the following code in .htcaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RRewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The issue is on the first line, because the code is written in the same line as the comment "BEGIN Wordpress".

When I fix this as

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
....
```

It works fine, but after few days again the site goes offline and when checked I found same issue.

I have restriction that I can't change the permission of .hataccess file to 444

Please help me slove this issue.

Comment: if I remember correctly there's a network.php file in wordpress that writes the htaccess, check to see if it's faulty in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit core file to get it resolve.

open rewrite.php from wp-inludes\rewrite.php and

go to line# 1786 and replace the existing code with `$rules = "\n<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>\n";`

and save your file to fix this issue permanently

Comment: Seems this is a great answer. Isn't it a bug in WP?

Comment: @Kannu some version of wordpress code uploaded/shipped with this issue

Comment: so its a known issue in WP. Thank you once again. You saved lot of my time... would invite you for dinner if possible... lol